# UitextFields in UIAlertView selecting iOS

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uialertview

I have three `UITextfields` in `UIAlertView`, while tap on one `UITextfield` and try to tap on other its not selecting and creating a problem, also problem of resigning first responder, is it not good choice of using `UITextfield` in `UIAlertView`

```
- (IBAction)heightMethod:(id)sender
{
    self.centimeterTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
    centimeterTextField.placeholder = @"  Centimeters";
    self.centimeterTextField.delegate=self;
    self.centimeterTextField.tag=3;

   [ self.centimeterTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

   [self.alertHeight addSubview: self.centimeterTextField];

    self.ptextfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 80.0, 80, 25.0)]; ptextfield.placeholder = @"   Feet";

    self.ptextfield.delegate=self;

    self.ptextfield.tag=4;

    [self.ptextfield setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.alertHeight addSubview:self.ptextfield];
    self.ptextfieldInches = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 80.0, 80, 25.0)]; ptextfieldInches.placeholder = @"   Inches";
    self.ptextfieldInches.delegate=self;
    self.ptextfieldInches.tag=5;

  [ptextfieldInches setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    [self.alertHeight addSubview:ptextfieldInches];

   [self.centimeterTextField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad];

    [self.ptextfieldInches setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad];

    [self.ptextfield setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad];

     self.alertHeight.tag=1;

   [self.alertHeight show];  
}
```

Comment: Yes, Please post code here

Comment: use Tag for Proper textfild and its Delegate Check with witch Textfild are calling. or May be you can forget Giving Delegate of one of the Three TextFiled so Check Properly.

Comment: please look at my code , i think i have added all tag and required parameters please wrapout this problem

Comment: check out this link http://technopote.com/customized-alertview/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (void) presentSheet {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Enter Information"
message:@"Specify the Name and URL" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

[alert addTextFieldWithValue:@"" label:@"Enter Name"]; 
[alert addTextFieldWithValue:@"http://" label:@"Enter URL"];

UITextField *tf = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
 tf.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
 tf.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet; 
 tf.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;

 tf.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
 tf.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
// URL field
 tf = [alert textFieldAtIndex:1];
tf.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing; tf.keyboardType =  UIKeyboardTypeURL;
tf.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert; tf.autocapitalizationType =  UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone; tf.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
[alert show]; 
}
```

Comment: its not workin, no declaration for addTextFieldWithValue  showing.

Comment: @Youaregreat I suggest to refere The iPhone Developer’s Cookbook pg. No 115

Comment: @ouaregreat this is not developed by me this code is from The iPhone Developer’s Cookbook that is really good source for ios beginners. i personally daily refer it.

Comment: No visible @interface for 'UIAlertView' declares the selector 'addTextFieldWithValue:label:' i am getting this wrning, please check

Comment: @Youaregreat : hope, you directly Copy and paste this code but try to understand this and create and your own alert view, i simply sown you how to write here code contain method presentSheet remove it also try. again i says refere cook Book if you can't then send me your email id i will send this book to you.

Comment: jignesh thank you for your appriciation, please send me the book, id=rameshrajput007@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You can now create a UIAlertView with a style.

UIAlertView now has a property - alertViewStyle that you can set to one of the enum values

**1. UIAlertViewStyleDefault**

**2.   UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput**

**3.   UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput**

**4.   UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput**

Once you've created the alert view, you set it style and display it. After dismissing the alert, you can access the contents of the fields using the textFieldAtIndex property of the alert view.

or else you can use this one also.,

```
IAlertView* dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
[dialog setDelegate:self];
[dialog setTitle:@"Enter Name"];
[dialog setMessage:@" "];
[dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
[dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];

UITextField *nameField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 45.0, 245.0, 25.0)];
[nameField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[dialog addSubview:nameField];
CGAffineTransform moveUp = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 70.0);
[dialog setTransform: moveUp];
[dialog show];
[dialog release];
[nameField release];
```

Hope this information helps. Thank you.

Comment: its good ,but for me its not enough, because i have added three text field for meter to feet and inche conversion, and while u entring value it shows all rthe value i continue .